# why save chart functionality not working ? even in official example?

Tags: extjs, ext.net

why save chart functionality not working ? even in official example ?

http://examples.ext.net/Examples/Chart/Area/Basic/

it's code sample for javascript i use it was working for 6 months now it's redirect to

http://svg.sencha.io/ with a blank page

```
<script>
          var saveChart = function (btn) {
              Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm Download', 'Would you like to download the chart as an image?', function (choice) {
                  if (choice == 'yes') {
                      btn.up('panel').down('chart').save({
                          type: 'image/png'
                      });
                  }
              });
          }
<script>
```

Comment: It appears the server is down... receive the following on the site from chrome dev tools: Status Code:503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity

Comment: yes i got the same respons from them here
http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?27687-why-save-chart-functionality-not-working-even-in-official-example&p=123200#post123200

 thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found another Option for exporting charts

i have used Export to server

http://examples.ext.net/Examples/Chart/Miscellaneous/Export_to_Server/